# Quantum Gamepad doesn't work on Xiaomi Redmi 1S

Tags: usb-on-the-go, game-controllers

I have Quantum PS2-like Gamepad which doesn't work on my Xiaomi Redmi 1S. My phone's Android version is 4.3.

I use a USB OTG cable which works fine with keyboards, mouses, and pen drives.

Whenever I attach the joystick, just the red light in the joystick blinks, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

USB OTG doesn't work when high power output is needed. It usually doesn't work with joypads which have analog sticks. If you want to use it, you'll have to attach USB hub with external power source, or make DIY externally-powered USB OTG.